# Can a website on safari give you a virus?

Tags: virus

I was browsing around on good ol' Sarari when all of a sudden, when I tapped on a website that I had successfully visited before, I was redirected to a site simply called Addware Detected !! On screen a notification popped up telling me that Addware/spyware may be on my iPad (2). It give a list of effects that it may have and tells me to contact IOS Tech support and list a number. There is a "ok" button at the bottom of the pop up but when ever I tap it it just comes back up and I cannot change tabs or open the history or anything. I had to download the Google app just to post this. Now what I want to know is is this real? And should I contact the number?

Comment: Update* I went to settings-safari and turned off "fraudulent website warning" and I was able to go into safari and close the pop up. I do t know if this was coincident or that was the solution but I am thankful nonetheless. But, I still want to know if it was a virus and I just turned off the pop up. Thank you.

Comment: Is this on ISX or iOS (my answer is iOS but I can change it = OS X I think could do a bit more but your description seems more like iOS)

Answer (score 3):

**Do not contact the number it is a scam.**

This is my advice from several sites including an [Apple support document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203987) Note the document covers both OS X and iPhone/iPad/iPod Touch.

On iOS this is just a javascript pop up which just affects the page you are on and is just a message. To get rid of it close the browser,  iOS 9 might then prompt you with a Block Alerts button, if so tap the button to stop showing alerts from that webpage.

If you can't close the page then force quit the browser and don't go back to that page.

The writer of the script wants you to ring and the discussion will include asking you for money, it is a scam.

Answer (score 0):

As Mark stated, whatever you do, don't contact the number. It's definitely a scam.

If your iPad is running iOS 9, you can use a content blocker with Safari. I use one called "Lionz", it's not perfect, but it's free and works well enough. When configured correctly, it should block the pop-up after the webpage is reloaded again and you should be able to leave the webpage.

Likely, your iPad doesn't have a virus. Unjailbroken iOS viruses are almost unheard of. It's probably a part of the webpage itself and you shouldn't have anything else to worry about. Just remember to update to the latest version of iOS (9.1 was released a few days ago) for the best security and report the scam to Apple.